# How to resolve invalid class “unmarkedFrame” object: obsCovData does not have M*obsNum rows.?

Tags: r, unmarked-package

I am trying to make an occupancy model using the R Package unmarked. I have a dataset which has occupancy, obvs covariates, and and site covarites, and I have written the code as follows:

```
umf <- unmarkedFrameOccu(y=as.matrix(Grebe_Presence_Data[,c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")]),   siteCovs=Grebe_Presence_Data[,c("Percent_Wetland", "Depth", "Distance_National_Park", "Distance_Shore", "Nets", "Aquaculture", "Distance_Settlement", "Distance_Road")],   obsCovs=Grebe_Presence_Data[,c("Percent_Wetland", "Transect_Length", "ObsTeam", "Methodology")])
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “unmarkedFrame” object: obsCovData does not have M*obsNum rows.
```

I tried to write it slighly differently, as follows:

```
umf <- unmarkedFrameOccu(y=as.matrix(Grebe_Presence_Data[,c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")]),   siteCovs=Grebe_Presence_Data[,c("Percent_Wetland", "Depth", "Distance_National_Park", "Distance_Shore", "Nets", "Aquaculture", "Distance_Settlement", "Distance_Road")],   obsCovs=list(date=Grebe_Presence_Data[,c("Percent_Wetland", "Transect_Length", "ObsTeam", "Methodology")]))
```

But only get the following error message

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  At least one element of obsCovs has incorrect number of dimensions.
```

I have checked and all the columns have the same number of rows, so I am not sure what the issue is. Does anyone have a solution?